# run php code if $players is between 5 and 9 in third span

Tags: php

Ok i edit my question i think i understand more now how to build a question.
The website: bit DOT ly/1MHItEH

I want to run a php code when span 3 is between 5 & 9.

The code which outputs this is `$players` and in the bottom there is a html output code

```html
<td><span style='text-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffca00; color: #ffca00; font-size: 20pt;'>". $players ."</span></td>
```

This php code outputs a html table with different values for every added server.


For example if i add a new server to servers.php it will create a new span for that server with new values. So basicly it reads and outputs different values for every server.

So how can i just run extra php code if the span 3 is between 5 & 9?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
   tr td, tr th { text-align: center !important; }
   tr td.motd, tr th.motd { text-align: left !important; }
</style>

</head>

<body style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; height: 20px; ">

<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'> 

</br>   
   
   <?php
   error_reporting(0);
   
   function openserveriai() {

   }

   function closeserveriai() {

   }

   function getnextstring(&$data) {
    $temp="";
    $counter=0;
    while (ord($data[$counter++])!=0) $temp.=$data[$counter-1];
    $data=substr($data,strlen($temp)+1);
    return $temp;
   }
    
   function getnextbytevalue(&$data) {
    $temp=ord($data[0]);
    $data=substr($data,1);
    return $temp;
   }

   function addServer($ip) {
    
    $map = '';
    $players = '';
    $maxplayers = '';
    $servername = '';
    $output = '';
    $live_server = '0';
    $packet = '0';
    $packet = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFTSource Engine Query\x00";
    $live_server = fsockopen("udp://".$ip);
     
    if(!$live_server)
    {
     $output = "Off";
    }
    else
    {
     fwrite($live_server, $packet);
     socket_set_timeout($live_server,1,0);
     $junk = fread($live_server,5);
     $status = socket_get_status($live_server);
     $do = 1;
     $server_info= "";
      
     while($do)
     {
      $str_1 = fread($live_server,1);
      $server_info .= $str_1;
      $status = socket_get_status($live_server);
      if($status["unread_bytes"] == 0) {$do = 0;}
     }
     fclose($live_server);
      
     if (strlen($server_info) > 0)
     {
      $success = 1;
      $junk = getnextstring($server_info);
      $servername = getnextstring($server_info);
      $map = getnextstring($server_info);
      $junk = getnextstring($server_info);
      $junk = getnextstring($server_info);
      $players = getnextbytevalue($server_info);
     }
      
     if ($players != '') {
      $players = $players;
     } else {
      $players = "0";
     }
      
     if ($maxplayers != '')
     {
      $maxplayers = $maxplayers;
     }
     else
     {
      $maxplayers = "0";
     }

     if ($output != "Full" and $players != "0" or $maxplayers != "0")
     {
      $output = $output;
     }
     else
     {
      $output = "<font color='#FF0000'>Offline</font>";
     }

     if ($map != '')
     {
      $map = $map;
     }
     else
     {
      $map = "--";
      $maxplayers = "--";
      $players = "--";
     }

     if ($servername != '') {
      $servername = $servername;
     }
     else
     {
      $servername = "--";
     }
    }
    if($players == $maxplayers && $players != '--')
    {
     $players = "" . $players . "";
    }
    else if($players > $maxplayers-3 && $players != '--')
    {
     $players = "" . $players . "";
    }
    else
    {
     $players = "" . $players . "";
    }
    if ( strlen($map) > 19 )
    {
     $map = substr($map, 0, 19) . '...';
    }
    
    echo "
     <tbody>
      <tr style='background: #10130d;'>
    ";
    if ($map == '--')
    {
     echo "<td><span style='background-color: #b85c5c; border-radius: .25em; padding: .2em .6em .3em; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt;'>Offline</i></span></td>";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "<td><span style='background-color: #5cb85c; border-radius: .25em; padding: .2em .6em .3em; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt; '>Online</i></span></td>";
    }
    echo "      
    
    <td><span style='color: #fff; font-size: 10pt;'>". $ip ."</span></td>
    <td><span style='text-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffca00; color: #ffca00; font-size: 20pt;'>". $players ."</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    ";
   }

   openserveriai();

   include ('servers.php');

   closeserveriai();
   
   ?>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check out [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/6634591)

Comment: So basically you want value of the third span ??

Comment: You can't simply 'run' a PHP (server-side) script via the client-side. You would need to post some data somewhere via http request. in order to 'trigger' the script.

Comment: I know the difference between javascript and php.<br>
Simple sed, if third span is between 5 & 9 then run php file or php include.

Comment: @AndersAndersson you don't know the difference between JavaScript and PHP as you're using JavaScript to check a condition and expecting to use PHP once that condition is met. Not possible.

JavaScript runs in a parsed document, in a parsed document PHP can't run because that is interpreted on the server. You will need to post to a URL to activate a script if that is the case.

Comment: Well can php do the same thing then? If .innerHTML of third span between 5 & 9 then execute php code?

Comment: No but it can check the value it places in that html if the table is created with php and add something to it on the server

Comment: where does the '5' come from?

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What does this php code do and what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: From $total and its in a php file. The php file prints out 5.

Comment: then do a test for `$total` in that php file, right there. And call a function or include a script when it matches your criteria (between 5 and 9). No need to mess around with the later rendered html.

Comment: As I understood it: you want to traverse generated html and make additional ajax calls to php backed as long number in a third column is between 5 and 9? Am I correct?

Comment: @Chris Cynarski yes. But i dont need to be on the site for that script to work. I edited my first question.

Comment: I remade my question from scratch can you take a look again?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 <?php
        $total = 5;
        if ($total >= 5 && $total <= 9) {
             //Between 5 and 9
        } else {
            // Not between 5 and 9
        }
  ?>

<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>  
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><span>First</span></td>      
    <td><span>Second</span></td>
    <td><span><?php echo $total; ?></span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can call that php page with

```
require('yourpage.php');
```

Comment: This question should be closed and remain unanswered. In the shape the question is now, no answer can fully answer the question as it is far to unclear what OP wants

Comment: sorry, just wanted to help him out.

Comment: Hello i remade the question from scratch. Hope my question is more clear now.